# How could extract parameter pack from variadic template type (e.g. std::tuple) in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

With C++ 11 How can I extract a variadic argument of a template type as a parameter pack?

Say we have template specialization type `Argument_t`

```cpp
...

template<typename F>
using Argument_t = ArgumentType<F>::type; // std::tuple of Args...
```

Now I would like to use this template specialization in another struct to copy the signature of the template argument to a method. e.g.

```cpp
template<typename F>
struct SomeStruct {

    // How can I do this where Args... is that of Argument_t<F>.
    void some_method(Args... args) 
    { 
        ...
        // Should have access to some_member_data
    };

    ...

    static int some_member_data;

}
```

Like this how could one use `Args...` where having `std::tuple<Args...>`. Or is there any better way instead of `Argument_t` providing `std::tuple<Args...>`.

Comment: You need template template parameter, smth like `template <template <...> typename TT, typename... Args> void foo(TT<Args...> obj){ using ArgsTuple=std::tuple<Args...>;}`

Comment: Also consider `void some_method(Args&&... args)` and `std::forward<Args>(args)...`

Answer (score 1):

I think simpler way is with specialization in your case:

```
template <typename Tuple> struct SomeStruct;

template <typename... Args>
struct SomeStruct<std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    void some_method(Args... args) 
    { 
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};
```